# Github Clone in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea, clone

I want to create a sparse matrix using `Efficient Java Matrix Library (EJML)`.This is the link (http://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page). I am using intellj I Idea for Java coding. In EJML website it is suggested that

The command to clone it is:
  git clone https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/ejml.git

I click on check out from version control. Then select Github from that and get a Error message. `Cannot run program "git.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`I solve this problem after installing Git. A new project folder created. But don't find where to write down my Java code.In normal Intellij Idea project a src folder created. Then I right click on it and create a class file. Here there is no option to create class file. I add a picture of my current state.

This is the homepage of Intellj Idea [image]

[image]

[image: After Complete of Cloning]

Thank You In advance

Comment: the amount time you spent on typing this question.. i wish you could have spent that time on reading about git :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will follow it next time. :)

Comment: How is your question related to Java language? Why do you use that tag?

Comment: Those who are working on Java and using matrices on there program may be familiar with EJML. If they are familiar with EJML they should know how to clone it. So that I tag Java.

Comment: @GlebKosteiko OP is trying to write a Java program using a Java library in a Java IDE. Just because it isn't a code question doesn't mean it doesn't involve Java.

Comment: @DavidConrad as for me, the cause of the issue is more related to environment configuration, than to something related to development on Java or Java ecosystem. That's why I asked about the tag - I'm not sure that someone who can help with some  Java-related questions will be able to help with this question.

Comment: @GlebKosteiko I think those who know Java and handling matrices in Java they can answer my question. Because creating your own matrix addition subtraction sparse matrix is a tedious work. Using in built matrix class is more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to *use* EJML, or do you want to *work on* EJML? It's unlikely you want to clone it.

Instead, create a project and add EJML as a dependency. Using Maven, add this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.ejml</groupId>
  <artifactId>ejml-all</artifactId>
  <version>0.33</version>
</dependency>
```

Using Ivy, add this to ivy.xml:

```
<dependency org="org.ejml" name="core" rev="0.33"/>
```

Using Gradle, add this to build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.ejml', name: 'core', version: '0.33'
```

Update: I tried adding it to a project of mine, and while the EJML web site mentions version 0.34, Maven Central only seems to have 0.33 currently.

To create a project in IntelliJ IDEA from scratch:

- Click "Create New Project"
- Make it a "Java Project" (default), and click Next
- Click Next to bypass creating from a template
- Give the project a thoughtful name, like "Sparse", and click Finish
- Right-click on the project at the upper left and click "Add Framework Support..."
- Check "Maven" and click "OK"
- In the pom.xml, add these lines after the  :

  org.ejml
          ejml-all
          0.33
- IntelliJ IDEA will prompt that the Maven project needs to be imported. Allow it.

On the left side under the project you can open src/main/java in the tree and right-click on java and choose New > Java Class and you should be ready to go.

Comment: I want to use EJML to create a Sparse Matrix.How to add EJML as dependency?

Comment: @EllenaMori What kind of project is it? Have you created a project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: I just want to create a Sparse Matrix using EJML package. But where should I create this .Java file. After cloning I get those option in my left hand side [.gitignore,.travis.yml,build.gradle,build.xml,change.txt,convert_to_ejml.py,gradle.properties,gradlew.but,Licese_2.0.txt,README.md,settings.gradle,External Libraries]

Comment: @EllenaMori Ah, it looks like you're using gradle? You'll want to add the `compile group` line above to the dependencies in `build.gradle` There should be a `src` folder you can create your Java class under. I included instructions for setting up a project using Maven. I'm not as familiar with gradle.

Comment: I create this project in D: drive. I have folder in D: drive name Github.Under Github there is a folder EJML.There is 5 folder in ejml.They are .idea,docs,examples,gradle,main.Under example folder there is src and test folder. src folder consist of some class files that is in build in ejml. ExampleSparseMatrix.java is in src folder. But I don't know I to use it in my code?

Comment: @EllenaMori Oh, wait. I think you followed the instructions from others about doing a `git clone` of the ejml project? You don't want that, you want to create your own project in IDEA and import the ejml library into it. Then you'll create, edit, and run your Java code within IDEA as well. I suggest you try the steps in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Download and install git on the machine before cloning from Intellij. Here's the [link](https://git-scm.com/downloads)